# google app engine not loading admin static media files

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-admin

I am new to django.  I am using Google App-engine and Google CloudSQL to serve a django1.2 project.  I've been following the tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial02/) and have hit a snag.

I enabled the admin back end in my settings.py, but when I go to http://www.examplesite.com/admin/ the css files aren't found.

The admin html page loads fine, but the static files give a 404.

Here's my app.yml:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"

builtins:
- django_wsgi: on
```

I left these as default in settings.py:

```
# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'
```

I know the files are located at google_appengine/lib/django_1_2/django/contrib/admin/media/

Do I need to copy those static resources into my project directory somewhere?  Or do I have a setting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GAE you need to make the static files accessible in your app.yaml

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers

Comment: Ended up creating a symlink to the contrib/admin/media directory and creating a handler to it, like you pointed out.

handlers:
- url: /media
  static_dir: static/media